# Canada Travel. Is it possible for me to apply for Canada Visa with an expired H1B Visa and a denied H1B Extension?

Tags: indian-citizens, canada, h1b-visas

I am an Indian citizen with an expired USA H1B Visa (Aug 1, 2019). My extension for H1B in the USA was denied. I received the denial status today. (September 26, 2019). I can probably get a new job in the USA. Is it possible for me to travel to Canada until my employer files a  H1B transfer/application for me?

My sister can sponsor me. I have been to Canada earlier and I know the process. But I had a valid visa then. I don't have a valid visa now.

Comment: It’s always possible to apply for a visa. What I think you really mean is ‘will I get a visa’, which no-one on TSE can answer with certainty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get a new job in the USA unless you have an approved H1b which you don't...
You'd have to leave the US and apply for a new one.

You can probably travel to Canada, though Canadian immigration authorities might have doubts about your intent to go to the country and deny you a visitor visa on the grounds that you're likely intending to go work there. Just having an expired H1b is no grounds for concern, the refusal for extension might raise some eyebrows as you will have to mention it on your visa application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to apply for Canadian visa,  they have own criteria of selection.  For  visa services is important to know that you have important link with your country. So they believe you will flight back to your country. If they see money on your bank account,  stable job,  car, house it's can help to get visa.  So for the embassy interview bring some bank statements,  letter from your employer...   good luck my friend!